# Creating a UID as a field in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to be able to create a UID as a field inside my collection in firestore, is that possible?

Ex: The UID would be a generated field that creates a "project" and that project will have it's own UID, so that it stays unique. How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Every collection can have an auto generated key and will by default.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're running into.  You can write whatever string you want into a document's field.  You can use whatever method you want to generate that string, if that's what you need to do.

Comment: @theblindprophet how can I do that? I'm so sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: @Jacob What are you using js?

Comment: From what I understood you want to create a custom id to for your document, correct? If that is the case, check this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document), in there you will see that you can you the method `.set()` by setting an id earlier like this `db.collection("collection").doc("new-doc-id").set(data);`, this will generate an id with whatever value you want to you new document (There are examples in a lot of languages in there). Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: It really helps us to help you if you 1) include the code in the question you're asking about and 2) Tag the question with your coding platform. JS? Swift? Assembly? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very possible

```
val id uuid = UUID.random()
    val city = hashMapOf(
            "UID" to uuid
            "name" to "Los Angeles",
            "state" to "CA",
            "country" to "USA"
    )
    
    db.collection("cities").document(uuid)
            .set(city)
            .addOnSuccessListener { Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!") }
            .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e) }
```